# How to create a test that calls is_front_page in phpunit?

Tags: php, unit-tests

I'm using `WP_UnitTestCase` but in my code I have this condition. `is_front_page` which I'm not sure how to simulate that in `PHPUnit`

This is the piece of code that I have

```
elseif ( is_front_page() ) {
    // logic
}
```

And this is how I go to a page

`$this->go_to( $this->post_obj->get_permalink() );`

How do I tell phpunit that this is the homepage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`is_front_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/) function calls [`wp_query::is_front_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/is_front_page/). If you [scroll down to look at the source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/is_front_page/#source-code), you will see the code you're looking to trigger:

```
elseif ( 'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front') && get_option( 'page_on_front' ) && $this->is_page( get_option( 'page_on_front' ) ) )
        return true;
```

To meet that condition, you'll just need to do this in the code to set up for the test:

```
update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
update_option( 'page_on_front', $post_id );
```